# How can I see my albums on Imgur, now that the link to "Album" is removed?

Tags: account-management, imgur

On Jan. 30 2019, I noticed that the "Album" link disappeared, as in the right screenshot beneath. The [one on the left](https://help.imgur.com/hc/article_attachments/360005565532/mceclip0.png) is from [Imgur.com](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/201771395-Change-Your-Password).

[image]

1. Anyone know why?
2. How can I see my albums then? I can see my pictures, but not in their albums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- albums are now in joined view with images
- click on your username
- select **Images**
- click on **All Images**
- and select an album you wish to view

[image]

[image]

- more confusion can be found **[here](https://community.imgur.com/t/cannot-see-access-album-button-when-clicking-on-my-name/67740/28)**

Comment: Is there no way to link to said albums?!

Comment: @MrYellow atm still not

Comment: They broke this too now... there's no hope.

Answer (score 2):

On Desktop, under your nic, choose "Images", and then from the new page, also under your nic, select "Gallery Profile".

Then Select your album.

Once the album opens, off to the right you have two buttons, public and hidden.

Click hidden and you'll get a link you can share.  I don't use 'Public' but I assume it makes your album public and probably also you get a share link.

Also instead of clicking 'hidden' you can just use the url link from the browser.  It's actually the same.

Comment: This is the correct answer. This also allows you to share links and give it a title.

Comment: cheese and rice they make this so difficult for no reason

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can't even share them because you can't link them anymore. They're just a way to filter and find your endless wall of images now.

Answer (score 0):

From your username icon in the top right, click 'posts'.  Then choose your album from the posts that show up below.  If you don't see it, note the tabs on the left- 'all', 'hidden' and 'public'.  Make sure you've chosen one that will list your album.